# Waves on a topological surface

Tags: waves, topology, research-level

Are there any formulas for wave motion on a topological surface, like a Mobius strip? If not, is this a valid opportunity for research?

Comment: Are you asking if you can solve the wave equation on a Möbius strip?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that by a "topological surface" you mean a surface with an interesting topology. You will need more than just a topological structure on your surface, because wave motion is governed by differential equations, and involves quantities like velocity.

The most general setting would be that of Riemannian manifolds, hence surfaces with a Riemannian metric in your case. The wave equation has a very direct analog in terms of the [Laplace-Beltrami operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator) $\Delta$, in terms of which it has exactly the same form as on Euclidean space:

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} + \Delta u = 0.$$

For the specific case of the Möbius strip, note that, like every surface, this can be given many different metrics. The only one of constant curvature however is the Euclidean metric. That means that locally the solutions are the same as those of the wave equation on $\mathbb R^2$, but we have restrictions on the global solutions: in one direction the solutions must be anti-periodic, in the sense that a shift along that vector must change the sign of the function $f(x + T) = -f(x)$.